# Are Facebook App publish_pages permissions required for my personal API access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to automate posting to my Facebook Business page. FB is forcing me to get an app review to approve the **manage_pages** and **publish_pages** permissions. I am not making an app for any other users, it is just for me.

**Is there a way to avoid app review since I am not creating a public app?**

When I try to use my user token (I am a page admin) in the API call it gives me the permission not available error. I can publish using the page token in Dev mode, (which makes all the posts hidden).

Sorry, this isn't a specific code question, If there is a better place to post this I will move it.

When I use my user token:

`(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.`

When I use my page token:

`(#200) The permission(s) manage_pages,publish_pages are not available. It could because either they are deprecated or need to be approved by App Review.`

Comment: rule of thumb: if it works, then it works. if not, then you need review ;)